# Move the center of an Openlayer map with javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I need to know how to recenter and zoom an Openlayer map with javascript? For example, I have a dropdown menu with cities, when I select a one of those cities the center and zoom will change to the current city and so on.

Comment: i find this question pertinent and it appears as a top suggestion in certain google searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do that. You will just have to pass the `lat` and `lon` of that city and pass to this function and it will put that in `center`.

```
function setCenter(lat,lon) {
    var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat);
    map.panTo(lonlat);
}
```

Where `map` is the object :

`map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {numZoomLevels: 2});`

All the examples of `openlayermap` exists here :

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/

Comment: Thanks, I used something similar: map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);