# Google map for individual User - web application

Tags: php, database, google-maps

How can I put google map link, so when clicked it goes to individual user address?
Every user address is stored in my database.

Comment: i recommend that you do not use google maps because, since they are proprietary products, they change the policies (and charge you).  i suggest  that you use openstreetmaps / openlayers - free community driven mapping platform.

you can find your answer [HERE in this SO question][1]

check [these examples][2] for other simple implementations of openlayers maps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698743/move-the-center-of-an-openlayer-map-with-javascript
  [2]: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ive done this in an earlier project...
Not sure if it will work, but here is my snippet:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=<?php echo $UserAddress; ?>&output=embed"></iframe>
```